# How to Redirect URL except GoogleBot?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a highly rank post on my blog and I just want to redirect it to my ClickBank affiliate link without losing my rankings. So I need to do this with `.htaccess` file. 
First it must check the `USER AGENT`,then it must check is there any "GOOGLE" word on that user agent string. If not, it should redirect user to my affiliate link. So far I tried following code without any success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^((?!google).)*$
RewriteRule http://myblog.com/post/ http://myafflink.com [R=301,L]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it similar to doorway approach which will finnaly lead you to ban in google?
It' not a good practice to show different pages to users and search engines.